# IIS Custom module works in 32 bit environment but not in 64 bit

Tags: windows, iis

I'm struggle to create a Custom classic module for IIS, I did it (and it is working fine) for 32 bit environment, but recompiling it in 64 bit, when I install it in IIS, the AppPool working in 64 bit stops to work looping into a lot of errors:

Into Application log:
The Module DLL D:\IISModules\mydll.dll failed to load.  The data is the error.

Into System log:
A listener channel for protocol 'http' in worker process '9080' serving application pool 'Utilities' reported a listener channel failure.  The data field contains the error number.

Running DebugViewer (Sysinternals) I can get this error:
w3wphost!WP_IPM::ReportListenerChannelStopped [wpipm.cxx @ 1743]:Report ListenerChannel stopped due to failure; ProtocolId:http, ListenerChannelId:0
iisutil!ReadMultiStringParameterValueFromAnyService [helpfunc.cxx @ 490]:Inetinfo: Failed reading registry value
Error(80070002): The system cannot find the file specified.

to stop the loop, I have to remove the Module from IIS

Module is written in C++

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by myself using Sysinternals Process Monitor, MSVCP140.DLL for 64 bit environment wasn't installed.

Installed this, the DLL works correctly

Hope this can help someone else
Thanks

Comment: Since Visual C++ Redistributable comes in x64 and x86 separately, it is a must to install both of them like you discovered.

Comment: If you can mark your answer, it will lead more people in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

You can try configuring IIS to run 32-bit applications, if you don't enable 32-bit, it will always try to load 64-bit. You need to follow these steps:

- Open IIS
- Go to current server->select your application pool
- Click Advanced Settings
- Set Enable 32-bit applications to True